# KMail Without Akonadi or Kontact in Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kmail, akonadi, kontact

I've searched the web as well as this site (including the other Stack Overflow/Exchange/etc. sibling sites) and have not found any concrete info. I've also searched the official KDE site and have still not found an answer.

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Y7000 laptop with the following:

- KDE Plasma 5.12.9.
- KDE Frameworks 5.44.0
- Qt 5.9.5
- Kernel 4.15.0-128-generic
- Intel i7-8750H
- 8 GB RAM

I had run KMail for several years and I really liked the interface and all of its features. What I did NOT like was the fact that Akonadi and Kontact, etc., seem to be required for KMail to work. KMail was the *only* component that I ran from this Akonadi mess and I have no desire for any of the other components launching (in the foreground OR background) and stealing resources from my system. Because of this, I had uninstalled KMail, Akonadi, Kontact and several other components about a year ago.

#NOTE: After the removal of these components, I have had no problems; this suggests to me that I had not removed anything necessary for my system to run properly.

My question is this:
Can I reinstall ONLY KMail and run it as a "standalone" program, or do I have to have all of these additional, unwanted components install, as well?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Akonadi is an implementation detail of KMail, without it KMail will not work.

Kontact is an app that groups KMail and other PIM applications (like KAddressBook and KOrganizer) into a single application. It is not needed to run KMail, but removing it will not give you any significant benefit

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas, for your response.
So is the bare minimum dep to run KMail Akonadi, or is there something else that I'm missing?